# LDAP exception when using own ldif file

Tags: spring-security, ldap

yesterday I asked a question, because I tried to access the CN property of a ldap object. Thanks to jzheaux I think I'm on the right way now. But I came across another problem. As soon as I try to get my own ldap path into the ldif file I get the following exception:

Caused by: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException: An entry with DN 'dc=parascus,dc=de' already exists in the server.

I'm using the following code:

LdapTestApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LdapTestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LdapTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

HomeResource.java:

```
@RestController
public class HomeResource {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Authentication authentication, Principal principal) {
        // Access of CN property
        Person person = (Person) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String[] cn = person.getCn();
        return "Home page of " + cn[cn.length - 1] + " alias " + principal.getName();
//        return "home";
    }
}
```

SpringSecurityConfig.java - The part to determine the person is from jzheaux (thankfully helped me with the initial problem I had):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=parascus,dc=de")
            .and()
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

    //
    // configuration for access of CN property
    // start
    //
    @Bean
    LdapAuthenticationProvider ldap(LdapAuthenticator authenticator) {
        LdapAuthenticationProvider ldap = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authenticator);
        ldap.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new PersonContextMapper());
        return ldap;
    }

    @Bean
    UnboundIdContainer ldapContainer() {
        UnboundIdContainer container = new UnboundIdContainer("dc=parascus,dc=de", "classpath:ldap-data.ldif");
        container.setPort(0);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    ContextSource contextSource(UnboundIdContainer container) {
        int port = container.getPort();
        return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://localhost:" + port + "/dc=parascus,dc=de");
    }

    @Bean
    BindAuthenticator authenticator(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
        BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        authenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[] { "uid={0},ou=people" });
        return authenticator;
    }
    //
    // configuration for access of CN property
    // end
    //
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:ldap-data.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=parascus,dc=de
```

ldap-data.ldif:

```
dn: dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: parascus

dn: ou=groups,dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=people,dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: uid=jsmith,ou=people,dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Smith, John
sn: Smith
uid: jsmith
userPassword: scrambled

dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=parascus,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: developers
ou: developer
uniqueMember: uid=jsmith,ou=people,dc=parascus,dc=de
```

When I remove the lines for getting the CN info, I can login to the page and get the text "Home" in the browser. I think I miss a little detail or I'm lost in the concept ... everything is possible.
I hope somebody can give me a hint what the cause is.

By the way, when I remove the section for dc=parascus,dc=de, hoping that it will now add this entry one single time, I get the following exception:

Caused by: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException: Unable to add entry 'ou=groups,dc=parascus,dc=de' because its parent entry 'dc=parascus,dc=de' does not exist in the server.

It might be that my program tries to add my ldif file two times and the second time it detects duplicates. But how can I tell my program to just add it once?

Kind regards

Parascus

Comment: The error says the entry `dc=parascus,dc=de` already exists, so just remove it (the first block) from the ldif. (remove all entries from your ldif file that are already on your server)

Comment: @EricLavault, thank you for this suggestion. That's something I already tried with the result that I get another Exception: Caused by: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException: Unable to add entry 'ou=groups,dc=parascus,dc=de' because its parent entry 'dc=parascus,dc=de' does not exist in the server. So if I give the dc=parascus,dc=de it is to much and if I remove it it is not enough. There has to be another reason like it builds up the ldap tree via spring boot generics and afterwards it trys to add the file content again, but it's already there.

Comment: Ok, you should update your post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I added this information to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was as I described above and now it's working. The problem was that I built up the LDAP tree by my application.configuration file. Aftwards my Configuration tried to build a new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource which referred to the same file. So it tried to insert the same entries again which caused the trouble.

Thanks for your efford.

Comment: hi parascus, what exactly did you do to tackle this issue. did you removed the file or cleared the ldap server ?

Comment: Hi, I kept the ldif file and embed it by application.properties like this:

   spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
   spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:users.ldif
   spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=parascus,dc=de